# Removing multiple spaces following line break

Tags: ruby, string, removing-whitespace

I want to remove multiple spaces and tabs that follow a line break, preserving the line break. Example string:

```
str = "This is a really good morning\n             "
```

How can I remove the multiple spaces after the `"\n"`?

Comment: You don't want to remove them if there is only one such character?

Comment: @sawa
No I don'w wanna, because actually my string is not only that, there are more string after the multispace and maybe tab, but I didn't add it in the question, because I don't know if it needed or not, I just asking if there are multi space or tab after the first linebreak it must be removed. I don't know what happen if there's a line break inside it too though.

Comment: But the important thing is, this question has been answered =). And for my case, I'm sure I can find out how to do wht I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using regular expression ([`String#sub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-sub)):

```
str = "This is a really good morning\n             "
str.sub(/[ \t]+\z/, '')  # `[ \t]+\z` matches spaces, tabs at the end of the string.
# => "This is a really good morning\n"
```

If you want to remove only **multiple spaces** (2 or more):

```
str.sub(/[ \t]{2,}\z/, '')
# => "This is a really good morning\n"
```

Comment: Oh I see, that's worked nice, I want to ask further, what the meaning of the dollar symbol?

Comment: What is the point of using `gsub` if you intend `$` to be the end of string?

Comment: @sawa, Ah. You're right. `sub` is enought. Thank you for pointing that. updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: @LuminaChen, EDIT previous comment: `$` matches at the end of the line (not at the end of the string). `\z` matches at the end of the string. See [Regular expression - Anchors - rubydoc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Anchors)

Comment: @sawa, I misunderstood `$` in Ruby regular expression. Thank you for giving me chance to correct it.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear. Here is what I have assumed, though other interpretations are possible:

- if the last non-whitespace character is the last character of the string, return the string;
- else if the whitespace following the last non-whitespace character includes no newline characters ("\n"), strip the trailing whitespace;
- else strip the trailing whitespace after the first newline character that follows the last non-whitespace character.

One consequence of these assumptions is that any newline characters that are followed by a non-whitespace character are treated the same as non-whitespace characters.

This one way to implement these assumptions:

```
def strip_it(str)
  len = str.strip.size
  i = str[len..-1].index("\n")
  i ? str[0,len+i+1] : str.rstrip
end
```

Some examples:

```
strip_it "This is a really good morning\n             "
  #=> "This is a really good morning\n"

strip_it "This is a really good morning \n             "
  #=> "This is a really good morning \n"

strip_it "This is a really good morning"
  #=> "This is a really good morning"

strip_it "This is a really good morning\n    cat      "
  #=> "This is a really good morning\n    cat"

strip_it "This is a really good morning\n    cat\n     "
  #=> "This is a really good morning\n    cat\n"

strip_it "This is a really good morning\n    cat \n     "
  #=> "This is a really good morning\n    cat \n"

strip_it "This is a really good morning\n    cat \n dog \n  "
  #=> "This is a really good morning\n    cat \n dog \n"
```

Lumina, it may seem like [I'm dancing on the head of a pin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_many_angels_can_dance_on_the_head_of_a_pin%3F), but one of the reasons I went into some detail is to show you why it is necessary to be precise in stating assumptions and requirements. In real applications, disaster awaits when requirements are not clear.

Comment: The question is not clear. If it meant to keep a line break if there is any, then this answer may add an unwanted one.

Comment: @sawa, that occurred to me as well, so I edited. I was also concerned about possible white space before the first newline.